# Show comments when Converting to Comment

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools

This is a consequence of [Are educational comments good?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184689/are-educational-comments-good/)

When working the flag review queue, I can choose to "Convert to Comment". When there are no comments at the post, it's simply a matter of clicking the button and it will happen.

However, when there are comments, it will ask me whether I want to convert with comments or just the post itself. I do not have that information at this point though. Since the comments are not initially shown, the only sensible option is to abort the process at that point to review and prune the comments.

To review the comment, I have to expand the answer and then check the comments (eventually having to expand those as well if there are more than five). Once done, I have to repeat the initial steps again, e.g. click Convert to Comment and then choose whatever I felt is appropriate.

This is especially annoying when the flag is valid and the comment is "this should have been a comment". It's a significant slowdown for me. I'd appreciate if we could show the comments immediately (when there is any) instead of forcing me to abort the process to check them manually.

Comment: Converting to comments should be exceptionally rare.  It should be reserved for those cases where good information will be clearly lost if you delete the answer, and mostly for those folks who already have enough rep to comment instead of answer (you don't want to be a "free pass" for people without commenting privileges being able to comment by posting an answer, and those constitute the bulk of non-answers).  Comments which are site-instructional, but were posted as answers, almost never merit preservation.